# Vs Code java The import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I recently moved from windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04, I'm a java developer, when I was on windows I installed Vs Code with the java Extension pack. On windows I never Had problem to make my daily work, but on ubuntu, every java file is marked as error, with the message "**The import cannot be resolved**", searching a litle bit, i found that you can execute the command **java:clean the java language server workspace**, but this does not fix the problem. I also remove the tmp files from the workspace located on:

> ~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage

- the current Version of Vs code is 1.41.1
- the current version of Java Extension Pack is 0.8.1

Any ideas?.

Regards!.

Edit: 
[all my java files are marked as error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxC54.png)

[inside of every java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pklbv.png)

[this is the result of the maven-install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYV9n.png)

Comment: Do you get that error when using `javac` in an Ubuntu terminal window to compile your Java code?

Comment: I'm working on a web application, if a use javac in a single file i get an error **cannot find symbol**, but, I use maven-clean -> maven- install, the build is marked as succeeded

Comment: So you're using Maven to do a successful build. Then where does the "The import cannot be resolved" error show?

Comment: in every java file inside the maven protect (I'm sorry for not point that out before), in the import section.

Comment: If every java file shows that error when building, then how can the build be marked as "succeeded"?

Comment: the error is not shown when building, is showed on the editor and in the folder of the project all java files are painted on red. but when I build with maven-install, is marked as succeded

Comment: could you show a screenshot with the issue ?

Comment: I just edit the question to show up the issue. regards!

Comment: Does VS Code know that this is a Maven project?

Comment: Yes, the plugin Maven for java (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven&ssr=false) recognize the proyect to do the builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after a while of searching, I found that the "maven for java" plugin was trying to download the maven plugin `maven-metadata.xml`, which wasn't available on my repo. this caused a conflict with the initial build that maven for java was doing. to avoid to update every time I opened vs code, I removed the option "update snapshots"

[image: VSCode Configuration Screenshot]

And the initial build was done.